The Text Don't appear in react native expo
I have a website where I publish certain stories that appear on the site normally, but some of the text of the stories does not appear in the application. When I update the stories and write the text manually, the story appears normally. The problem is only when I copy text from another platform or site.
What is the cause of this problem?
i'm tried RenderHtml library but not solution
